# Vector Relations in Minkowski Space

Tags: geometry, general-relativity

Consider $\mathbb{R}^4$ equipped with the Lorentz inner product:
$$\eta(X,Y)=x^0y^0-x^1y^1-x^2y^2-x^3y^3$$

Let $X,Y\in\mathbb{R}^4$, $X\not=0$ and $Y\not=0$, two future-causal (this means: $\eta(X,X)\le0$ and $x^0>0$) vectors.
I want to show that the following points are equivalent:

1. $\eta(X,Y)=0$
2. $\eta(Z,Z)=0$ for $Z:=X+Y$ (this means $Z$ is lightlike)
3. $\eta(X,X)=\eta(Y,Y)=0$ and the vectors $X$ and $Y$ are parallel

I cannot find a "starting point" for the proof. I always think that a special condition is missing. For example:
If I assume that 1. and 2. holds, than it is easy to prove the second point:

$$0=\eta(X,X)+2\eta(X,Y)+\eta(Y,Y)=\eta(X,X+Y)+\eta(X+Y,Y)=\eta(X+Y,X+Y)$$

In addition I'm confused: The first point means, that $X$ and $Y$ are orthogonal. So how is it possible, that $X$ and $Y$ are parallel (which is claimed in the third point)?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To address your point of confusion, "orthogonal" does not have the same intuitive content in Minkowski space as it does in Euclidean space. As an example, every light-like vector is orthogonal to itself! Take the light-like vector $\langle1,1,0,0\rangle$ for instance.

Comment: Also, I suggest that you edit your question to include the definition of "future-causal".

Comment: Take $X=(1,2,0,0)$ and $Y=(2,1,2,0)$ and verify that they are future-causal and that (1) is satisfied. Then show that (2) and (3) are not satisfied. In other words, these points are not equivalent.

Comment: The counterexample of @AndreySokolov makes me suspect that the "future-causal" inequality is backwards. If instead it were $\eta(X,X) \ge 0$ then I think 1, 2, 3 would indeed be equivalent.